# React buttons I want to change their styles when they are pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`export default function Ratings(props){
const[hover,setHover] =useState(false); // checks for hover state
const [com, setCom] = useState(false);  //checks for click state

```
function isHover(){
    setHover(true);} //connects to onMouseOver event then sets the hover state

function isNotHover(){ //connects to onMouseLeave event then sets the hover state
    setHover(false);}

function op(){              //Send the Id of the rating button back to app.js so
    props.op(props.id);}    // it can be then forwarded to another page
   

function designs(){           //connects the click to sate, if the state is true it makes it false
    com ? setCom(false):setCom(true)} // and vice verca 
    

function bth(){     // I have two functions on click so this combines both 
    op()            //the functions and gives it as one to the clicke event 
    designs()}

    pressed //is style after clicked
    rateStyle //is style before clicked
return(
<div style={hover|| com  ? pressed: rateStyle} onMouseOver={isHover}
 onMouseLeave={isNotHover} onClick={bth} >
{props.valN}
</div>)
```

}`I have five rating buttons and I want to unclick the already clicked button when another one is clicked. By clicking I mean, When I click one of the buttons their style is changed mainly background colour now I want when somebody presses another rating I want the style for the previously clicked button to go back to normal and the newly pressed button to go to active state help.

Comment: Can you post your component code?

Comment: I have added the code in edited version

Answer (score 0):

I used this method for this question.

inside your button

```
<button id="button" onClick={
        (e) => {
            if(res === "unpressed"){
          //if button is pressed for first             
          //time
             e.target.style.backgroundColor ="rgb(195, 197, 64)";
  setRes(pressed);
  //Update res into false
      }else{
      //if button is pressed for second             
       //time
   e.target.style.backgroundColor ="rgb(195, 17, 64)";
  setRes(unpressed);
  //Update res into false
      
  }
  }
        }>
  STAR

</button>
```

using Hooks

```
import { useState } from "react";

const [res,setRes] = useState("unpressed");
```